# Dynamically structured mySQL database for an Airline Reservation App

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am working on a personal project and needed some guidance with a mySQL database.  I am trying to simulate an airlines reservation system where a user has a personal account added to an Accounts db table (with username and password information).  Then I have my Flights db table to store all of the available flights.  The Flights db table has all of the flights with information (columns) on departure city, arrival city, departure time, arrival time, price, available seats, and seat capacity.

My question is:
When a user books a flight I must update the available seat value (int) in the Flights table.  But then I also must add the flight to the user's account in the Accounts table.  I am wondering how to handle this in mySQL, do I have to add a new column to the Accounts table with the corresponding flight's table index from the Flight's db table. Then continue adding a booked flight column as a user books flights to keep track of all the flights a user has booked?  Is there a better way to update the Accounts table with flights booked information?

All help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, I would probably go about this a little differently.  You may think about adding an additional table that tracks seat reservations.  Something like:

TABLE: Accounts

```
ID | First Name | Last Name | Username | Password
```

TABLE: Flights

```
ID | DepartureCity | ArrivalCity | DepartureTime | Price | SeatingCapcity
```

TABLE: Reservations

```
ID | Account_ID | Flight_ID | SeatNumber
```

You can then use SQL functions and math to determine the number of seats available on a particular flight and maintain just the Reservations table when making updates.  This also links all flights a particular account is associated with and is not "hard coded" to a particular column. (ie: A user can reserve more than one flight)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this is to introduce a new table `Bookings`. A possible structure might be

```
CREATE TABLE Bookings (user_id INTEGER NOT NULL, flight_id INTEGER NOT NULL);
```

Then you can fetch all flights of a given user by

```
SELECT f.* FROM Users u 
  LEFT JOIN Bookings b ON u.id = b.user_id 
  LEFT JOIN Flights f ON b.flight_id = f.id 
  WHERE u.id = ?
```

And count the bookings for a given flight by

```
SELECT count(*) FROM Flights f
  LEFT JOIN Bookings b
  WHERE f.id = ?
```

This structure has several advantages:

- You don't have to change the schema if users book more and more flights. Changing the schema of your database is a quite complex an expensive operation. (BTW: There is a maximum column count in MySQL)
- You have an point where you can add further fields that are concerned with bookings. Maybe you want to track reservations.
- Its more natural to fetch and add data. If you add columns `booked_flight_1` `booked_flight_2` and so on. You have to check which slot isn't already taken, which gets more and more complex when you consider deletions. Here it as easy as running this

  ```
  INSERT INTO Bookings (user_id, flight_id) VALUES (1, 2)
  ```

If have to check if a given flight is available, it might be better to check this using your program and insert the booking into the database, if it is.

Joins and transactions might be the techniques you will find useful. The MySQL documentation and every good book on relational databases will give you an introduction in this. Your question sounds to me, as a classical instructional example.

Comment: Thanks for this gregor, it helps a lot